# Need 2 text boxes with 100% width, divided into 2 (50% x 50%) along with a submit button

Tags: html, css

I need 2 text boxes stretch into 100% browser width, along with a submit button.. all three should be in one line, I tried to stretch it but it's not happening... any ideas?

**Code:**

```
.search-input{
width:100%;
border:#CCC solid 1px;
}

<div style="float:left; width:auto; margin-right:10px;"><input name="" type="text" class="search-input" /></div>
<div style="float:left; width:auto;"><input name="" type="text" class="search-input" /></div>
<div style="float:left;"><input name="" value="submit" type="button" /></div>
```

Comment: Why are the `input` elements wrapped in `div` elements? Can that HTML be changed at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you need 3 things in one line you can't have even one of this with width: 100%.
Try using 40% for each text and 18% for the button, more or less like this:

HTML

```
<div>
<input type = 'text' class = 'text item'>
<input type = 'text' class = 'text item'>
<input type = 'button' id = 'button' class = 'item'>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.text{
width: 40%;
}
#button{
width: 28%;
}
.item{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know how many inputs you have, just stretch them the correct amount:

```
<div class="border">
    <input type="text" class="line" />
    <input type="text" class="line" />
    <input type="submit" class="line" />
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>


.border {
    border:1px solid red;
}

input.line {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joeterry/m96B4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="40%"><input name="" type="text" class="search-input" /></td>
        <td width="40%"><input name="" type="text" class="search-input" /></td>
        <td><input name="" value="submit" type="button" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Width: auto` will not get you anywhere.  If you want them to be 50% and 50% then you need to tell them to be 50%.  There is a catch here, if you want the button to be included on the same line, then you need to calculate its width as well.  You also need to calculate margin, padding, and border space into your total width as well, and obviously, you can't have more than 100%.

What I have done is to make each div 43.5% wide, give the first div a 3% margin, and make the submit button 10% wide.

http://jsfiddle.net/v9Em7/

**HTML:**

```
<div style="float:left; width: 43.5%; margin-right:3%"><input name="" type="text" class="search-input" /></div>
<div style="float:left; width: 43.5%;"><input name="" type="text" class="search-input" /></div>
<div style="float:left; width: 10%;"><input name="" value="submit" type="button" /></div>
```

Of course, it's always recommended to avoid inline styling whenever possible.  It cuts down on the code you have to write, it's easier to understand, and it's best practice.  I would suggest doing this...

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input"><input name="" type="text" class="search-input" /></div>
<div class="input last"><input name="" type="text" class="search-input" /></div>
<div class="submit"><input name="" value="submit" type="button" /></div>
```

**CSS:**
    .input {float:left; width: 43.5%; margin-right:3% }
    .last { margin: 0; }
    .submit { float:left; width: 10%; }